# how to create a rewrite rule in htaccess with .(dot or period) in the parameter of the url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

here is my sample url:

**http://mydomain.com/folder/subfolder/index.php?site=www.othersite.com**

i want to rewrite it this way:

**http://mydomain.com/folder/subfolder/www.othersite.com**

i tried

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /folder/subfolder/

RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9\\-\\.]+)$ index.php?site=$1 [L]
```

i printed the array $_GET and returns the value of the 'site' parameter as 'index.php', it didn't return 'www.othersite.com'

how can this be done?

thanks,

Comment: To use . in a regex, you can escape it with \. but in your case, I don't see what is your problem with dots.

Comment: RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-_-]+)$ index.php?site=$1 [L]

this works fine if the value of the parameter 'site' has no .(dot or period)

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood your requirement and provided you opposite solution earlier. Please see my answer below, it should work for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this rule in your .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^site= [NC]
RewriteRule ^(folder/subfolder)/(.*)$ /$1/index.php?site=$2 [L,NC,QSA]
```