# trying to rewrite url in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have url

```
http://www.url.com/business/index.php?biz=andrewliu
```

I'm trying to accomplish so it will be

```
http://www.url.com/business/andrewliu
```

I tried to have this:

```
RewriteRule ^/?([a-z0-9_-]+)/?$ /index.php?biz=$1 [L]
```

or

```
RewriteRule ^/?([a-z0-9_-]+)/?$ /business/index.php?biz=$1 [L]
```

doesn't work?

Help me?

Edit:

I have this

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
```

prior to the rewriterule

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends in which directory your `.htaccess` file is.

For the root directory try this one:

```
RewriteRule ^/?business/([a-zA-Z0-9_-\.]+)/?$ /business/index.php?biz=$1 [L]
```

If your `.htaccess` file is in the business directory that of your statments should work fine:

```
RewriteRule ^/?([a-zA-Z0-9_-\.]+)/?$ /index.php?biz=$1 [L]
```

Comment: the htaccess is in the root directory. However, it seems like its not working properly.

Comment: can i have more than one htaccess file? should i place one in each directory?

Comment: Do you have activated the `ModRewrite` with the line `RewriteEngine on`? It is possible to use multible `.htaccess` files but you should know that the one in the deapest level has the highest priority.

Comment: Is it possible the the *usernames* have big letters? You could also try to remove the slash at the beginning of your script file where you redirect to.

Comment: i figured it out. I originally had a .com or something as my username, and i guess I can't have that

Comment: Try that one: `RewriteRule ^/?business/([^/]+)/?$ /business/index.php?biz=$1 [L]`

Comment: that gave me a 500 error too. I used this example from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5812734/how-to-create-a-rewrite-rule-in-htaccess-with-dot-or-period-in-the-parameter

Comment: Have a look to your error.log of your apache. I see no errors in my .htaccess rules...

Comment: no error shows up =\ weird. but the example i used worked fine?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15880/discussion-between-rekire-and-andrewliu)

Answer (score 0):

RewriteRule ^business/([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+)/?$ business/index.php?b=$1 [L]

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear from your examples whether you want "biz" or "business" or "b". I'm taking a guess that you want "biz", in which case your rule should be:

```
RewriteRule business/(.*) /index.php?biz=$1 [L]
```

Or maybe you want:

```
RewriteRule ([^\/]*)/(.*) /index.php?$1=$2 [L]
```